# Определение статуса набора текста собеседником

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, websocket, чат, соцсети

У меня в связи с использованием социальных сетей и чатов возник следующий вопрос. Пусть, например, я переписываюсь с Александром. Я получил сообщение от него и пишу ответное сообщение. В процессе написания ответного сообщения у Александра в мессенджере возникает индикатор процесса ввода "Михаил пишет ...", причем возможны 2 варианта:

**1.** индикатор отображается **спустя** некоторое время **после** начала написания мною сообщения  и продолжает отображаться **до** некоторого момента до нажатия на кнопку Отправить;

**2.** индикатор процесса отображается **с** момента начала написания сообщения и вплоть **до** нажатия на кнопку Отправить.

**1)** Как определить промежуток времени отображения индикатора процесса "Михаил пишет ..." - ведь когда я нажму на кнопку Отправить компьютеру заранее неизвестно и каким образом определяется интервал до?

Как организовать с помощью вебсокетов яваскрипта отображение индикатора процесса, так чтобы точки в строке "Михаил пишет **...**" добавлялись через определенные интервалы времени и чтобы весь интервал времени отображения индикатора находился **между** началом написания сообщения и нажатием на кнопку Отправить?

**2)** Как организовать с помощью вебсокетов яваскрипта отображение индикатора процесса, так чтобы точки в строке "Михаил пишет **...**" добавлялись через определенные интервалы времени и сам индикатор отображался **сразу** после начала написания сообщения и вплоть до момента нажатия на кнопку отправить?

**P. S.** Подытоживая и говоря проще - **как определить время отображения индикатора процесса ввода в строку сообщений в соц сетях** и **как это программно организовать** с помощью кода (вебсокетов яваскрипта)?

Если есть варианты без вебсокетов, тоже приводите.

Если есть более точные формулировки вопроса, редактируйте.

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, то пишите - я проясню. Если есть варианты как загуглить, тоже пишите.

Comment: 1. При начале ввода в текстовое поле (можно использовать событие ```input```) отправить методом ```send()``` информацию о том, что Михаил начал печать. Если нужно через какое-то время после ввода, то отправить эту информацию через тот же ```setTimeout()```. При этом можно запустить счётчик времени (например, на 3 секунды), который обнуляется при каждом изменении текстового поля и завершается, когда перестали вводить текст. Как только перестали вводить текст (изменять значение текстового поля, то есть уже не работает ```input```), отправляем ```send()```, что Михаил уже не печатает ничего.

Comment: 2. Так просто же анимация по сути, разве нет? Анимация появления/исчезновения точек, пока этот индикатор есть. Индикатора нет - нет анимации точек. Или что-то иное подразумевается?

Comment: То есть что можно было бы спросить у поисковика? Как определить начало ввода в текстовое поле? Как определить, когда пользователь завершил ввод в текстовое поле? CSS-анимация загрузки три точки

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st Можно показывать, что собеседник печатает текст, если за последние N секунд было M нажатий клавиш в поле ввода текста, константы определить опытным путем. В событии onkeypress или onchange вставлять в массив времен `push`-ем время нажатия на клавишу и если значения последних M элементов массива времен лежат в интервале CurrentDateTime-N, CurrentDateTime, то шлем `send`-ом по вебсокету статус "печатает".